# PHP - rendering template

Tags: php, soap

I have this code to render a template (I am new to PHP so bear with me)

```
function __destruct()
    {
        /*
        * It's render the template 
        *
        */
            $this->_template->render();
    }
```

with this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/soap/php/library/controller.class.php on line 73`

This is the construct

```
function __construct($model, $controller, $action) 
    {
        /*
        * A default constructor which creates objects of the template and model
        * @param string model, controller and action.
        * @return
        */

        $this->_controller = $controller;
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->_model = $model;

        $this->$model = new $model;
        $this->_template = new Template($controller,$action);

    }
```

Let me know if you think I should add anything more. I am new to PHP and am trying to get this application working. Any ideas welcome!!

Update: the whole class

```
<?php
/*
*
* controller.class.php - Controller class will be used as the base class 
*                        for all our controllers
*
*
*   The above class is used for all the communication between the controller, 
*   the model and the view (template class). It creates an object for the 
*   model class and an object for template class. The object for model class 
*   has the same name as the model itself
*
*
* We are not including the ?\>  to avoid injection of any extra whitespaces in our output.
*
*
*/
class Controller extends Validation
{

    protected $_model;
    protected $_controller;
    protected $_action;
    protected $_template;


// ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*


    function __construct($model, $controller, $action) 
    {
        /*
        * A default constructor which creates objects of the template and model
        * @param string model, controller and action.
        * @return
        */

        $this->_controller = $controller;
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->_model = $model;

        $this->$model = new $model;
        $this->_template = new Template($controller,$action);

    }


// ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*


    function set($name,$value)
    {
       /*
        * Set the variables from the controller to the template as a variables.
        * @param string name,value
        * @return
        */
        $this->_template->set($name,$value);
    }


// ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*


    function __destruct()
    {
        /*
        * It's render the template 
        *
        */
            $this->_template->render();
    }


}
```

Validation class:

```
<?php
/*
*
* pdoconnectionclass.php - Validation is used to validate any input data to the website
*
*
*   The above class is used for checking every data that are the user wrote it and are going
*   to be stored in the database. For each type of input there is an appropriate function 
*   to check it before is going to be store in the database.
*
*
* We are not including the ?\>  to avoid injection of any extra whitespaces in our output.
*
*
*/

    class Validation
    {

        public function isEmpty($check_var) 
        {
        /** Check if the input value is empty or not
        *   If is empty then return true back on the main program
        *   else return false
        */

            if (empty($check_var)){
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


        public function isInt($check_var) 
        {
        /** Check if the input value is integer
        *   and if Yes then return false else if not and is not int return false
        */
            if (is_int($check_var)) {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }

        }

        public function isPositive($check_var) 
        {
        /** Check if the input value is positive
        *   and if Yes then return false else if not and is not int return false
        */
            if ($check_var > 0) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;

            }

        }

        public function checking_phone($check_var) 
        {
        /** Check if the input value is a phone
            Check if the if the characters of $check_var
            are equal to 14 if the value has 0044 or if are 11
            if they start from 07. Then check if is positive
            and then removes the 0 from 07 and adds 44 at the beginning
        */
            if (strlen($check_var) == 11)
            {
                if ($this->isPositive($check_var) == true)
                {
                    if (($check_var >= '07000000000') && ($check_var <= '07999999999'))
                    {
                        $temp_phone = "44";
                        $temp_phone .= substr($check_var, 1);
                        return $temp_phone;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (strlen($check_var) == 14)
            {
                if ($this->isPositive($check_var) == true)
                {
                    if (($check_var >= '00447000000000') && ($check_var <= '00447999999999'))
                    {
                        $temp_phone = substr($check_var, 2);
                        return $temp_phone;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else if (strlen($check_var) == 12)
            {
                if ($this->isPositive($check_var) == true)
                {
                    if (($check_var >= '447000000000') && ($check_var <= '447999999999'))
                    {
                        return $check_var;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


        public function checkforXSS($check_var) 
        {
        /** Gets the input value and prevents HTML from being embedded, 
            and therefore prevents JavaScript embedding as well. 
            Return a safe versions of the input.    
            The htmlentities() function converts both double and single
            quotation marks to entities and the text to ASCII compatible multi-byte 8-bit Unicode.
        */
            htmlentities( $check_var, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
            return $check_var;
        }



        public function filter_var_int($var)
        {
        /** Filters a variable with the specified filter.
        */
            return filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        }


        public function filter_var_string($var)
        {
        /** Filters a variable with the specified filter.
        */
            return filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }


        public function filter_var_email($var)
        {
        /** Filters a variable with the specified filter.
        */
            $temp = '';
            $temp = filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $temp = filter_var($temp, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            return $temp;
        }       

        public function create_salt_password($username)
        {
        /** Creates a hash value for the password using 
            a prefixed random unique identifier value with a static characters and the username
        */
            $salt = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) .AUTH_SALT .strtolower($username));
            return $salt;
        }

        public function get_activation_code()
        {
        /** Creates an activation code for the user
        */
            return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you include the entire class that these functions are a part of? You have these functions inside a class right?

Comment: @CaseyFlynn I have updated with the entire class

Comment: Try appending var_dump($this->_template); after assigning it to see what object is returned by new Template($controller,$action);

Comment: @CaseyFlynn doesn't `new` always either return an object, or throw an exception?

Comment: We need to know more about Validation

Comment: Added that as well, it's weird because a friend says it was working on his Windows PC fine but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation:

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or **in any order during the shutdown sequence**.

Notice that when the destructors are running as a result of your script ending, they may run in any order, which may leave you with references to objects that have already been destructed. It's not clearly documented, but this implies that you can't safely access other objects from the destructor function, since they may no longer exist.

What's probably happening here is that the `Template` object is being destroyed first, resulting in the error when you then try to access it from your `Controller` destructor. That would also explain why it works on some machines and not others - since the destruction order is undefined and could vary widely between different machines.

This problem doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but according to [this random page](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=912), you're not the first person to encounter this problem:

> ...or when the end of the script is reached and PHP ends the request. The latter situation is delicate because you are relying on some objects that might already have had their destructors called and are not accessible anymore. So, use it with care, and don’t rely on other objects in your destructors.

---

The real solution to all this is to **not have this type of functionality in your destructor**. It's much cleaner to have something like a `renderHTML()` method that you manually call at the end of your script, instead of having some hidden behaviour that happens automatically.

See these other questions for more details:

- [Is using php destructor appropriate for displaying HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933206/is-using-php-destructor-appropriate-for-displaying-html)
- [Updating database on __destruct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500595/updating-database-on-destruct)

If you really need it to happen automatically, I'd recommend looking into [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) instead. You could change the `Controller` destructor to a regular method named something like `renderHTML`, and register to have that method run automatically on shutdown by putting this line in your constructor:

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'renderHTML'));
```

The `array()` in there is one of the ways to specify a [callback method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) in PHP.

Comment: Hi I have added the entire class, any ideas?

Comment: @jcansyi Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm not sure I follow your answer as I'm very new to PHP.

Comment: @germainelol The real solution is to not use the destructor for something like this. I've updated the end of my answer a bit more to expand on some of your other options.